# Keep animation when changing viewController

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to code an `animation` behind the profile picture, in order to encourage the user to click on it.
It's a circle which become bigger and smaller then.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {

     self.bouncedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
        1.3, y: 1.3)

      }, completion: nil)

}
```

[image]

The problem is that, when I go to another `viewController`, the animation is stopped and the circle stays like you can the on the screen shot. Do you know how I could avoid this issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I change the `viewController`"? Are making some edits somewhere, do you present some other UIViewController over this one, or what is the thing that stops the animation? Preferably include the code as well

Comment: Sorry it's not very clear ... I mean for example when I change the tab, or when I got to another viewController

Comment: OK, so when you change a tab to another viewController, the animation is paused wherever it was at the moment of change, and does not finish, that is the issue, right?

Comment: @KevinB I assume If you're animating on an instance of a view in a viewController and then switching to another viewController you must have a new instance, and so you'd have to create another animation.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Not exactly, it's stopped at 1.3 scale (the maximum) even if the circle was at 1.0 for example

Answer (score 2):

Do a transform to .identity on ViewDidAppear. Something similar to below code:

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewToAnimate: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.viewToAnimate.transform = .identity
    animateView()
}

func animateView(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {

        self.viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
            1.3, y: 1.3)

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

}

The problem as you might have guessed is that the UIView.animate is only called on the ViewDidLoad method and since we don't have access that code while returning to this ViewController from another, it is better to start the animation in the ViewWillAppear method.

If the same issue occurs when you switch between tabs, then please make a separate UIView subclass for the view that you want to animate and proceed as follows:

```
class AnimateView: UIView {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?) {
    super.willMove(toWindow: newWindow)
    self.transform = .identity
    animateView()
}

func animateView(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {

        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
            1.3, y: 1.3)

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Here, you have taken the animate function to the UIView object and whenever the view appears, the animation will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't yet have a satisfying answer yet (at least that would satisfy me), but I would like to add at least some insight to which I was able to get by a bit of experimenting.

First of all, it seems that the animation gets ended when the `viewController` is not currently the one presented. In your case that means that the animation stops and finishes with the state, in which the view is 1.3 times bigger, and stops repeating. `layoutSubviews` gets called only when you present it the first time. At least the `viewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called only at the beginning and not when you go back (so `layoutSubviews` will not get executed when the view reappears) - so the animation won't get restarted.

I tried to move the animation to the `viewDidAppear` of a `UIViewController` - that did not work either, because stopping animation resulted in state in which the view was already scaled 1.3 times. Resetting the state to `CGAffineTransform.identity` before creating the animation did work.

Now as I said, this can serve you as a workaround on how to get it working, however, I think what you really are looking for is some hook that would tell your view (not viewController) that it got presented again. But the following minimal example can at least help others to take a look at it and not start from scratch.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, timingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters(animationCurve: .linear))

    init(title: String) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.title = title
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let animatableView = UIView()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        animatableView.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 400, width: 100, height: 100)
        animatableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        view.addSubview(animatableView)

        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            self.animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
                1.3, y: 1.3)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print("\(self.title) >> Lay out")
    }
}

let tabBar = UITabBarController()
tabBar.viewControllers = [MyViewController(title: "first"), MyViewController(title: "second"), MyViewController(title: "third")]
tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = tabBar
```

**EDIT**

I added few lines to check if the `self.animatableView.layer.animationKeys()` contains any animations, it seems that switching tabs removes the animation from the view's layer - so you have to find a way to add the animation everytime the view reappears.

**EDIT 2**
So I would go with @SWAT's answer and use `willMove(toWindow:)` instead of `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the completion block, where you will create the first state of view. For example:

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat,  .autoreverse], animations: {

```
 self.bouncedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
    1.3, y: 1.3)

  } completion: { _ in
        self.bouncedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
    1.0, y: 1.0)
    }
```